# What wavelengths are most commonly used in laser-scanners and LIDAR systems?

Tags: lidar, laser, rangefinder

In Photography SE I've just asked [LIDAR burnout; ways to check for damaging infrared lasers before shooting besides looking for posted warnings?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/104325/50110) and discussed a camera that was damaged by a self-driving car's LIDAR system at the recent CES show.

The article linked there mentions the powerful "[fiber laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_laser)" used by that car's LIDAR system. For those I normally think of infrared wavelengths around 1500 or 1600 nm used in communications, but for simple semiconductor lasers based on III-V material the wavelengths are often around 800 or 900 nm.

This is just from personal memory. I'm wondering if I've got it right, and/or if there are other sources for common laser wavelengths used in obstacle detection and ranging.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Most Velodyne LIDARs (very commonly used on autonomous vehicles), use [905 nm diode lasers](https://velodynelidar.com/lidar/products/manual/63-9113%20HDL-32E%20manual_Rev%20G.pdf), and so do many Hokuyo laser scanners and SICK LIDARs.

A new company, Ouster, uses [850 nm lasers](https://www.autosensorsconf.com/sites/autosensorsconf/files/assets/6D%20LiDAR%20Face-Off%20Ouster_Mardirosian.pdf), claiming that their choice of lower wavelength is because the "atmospheric water absorption is orders of magnitude lower than at 905nm".

Some more info: https://velodynelidar.com/newsroom/guide-to-lidar-wavelengths/

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think it has answered your question adequately.

Answer (score 2):

Both 1550nm and 900nm ranges are used in different lidars.

Velodyne and majority others use 905nm lasers because these diodes are really cheap.

1550nm are used when there is a need for very long distance measurement range, such as [Luminar](https://spectrum.ieee.org/cars-that-think/transportation/self-driving/under-the-hood-of-luminars-long-reach-lidar), as the eye safety threshould is several orders of magnitude higher for this wavelength than 905nm.

In principle, the laser has to be very very high power to distroy a camera. Unfortunately most of these lidar start-ups are still in developing phase, and the so called Class 1 is the goal to achieve. Be careful not to look at the start-up's lidars.

Comment: Thank you for this advice "do not look at the start-up's invisible light rays when there are no warning signs" ;-)